How to prove that this function involving binomial coefficients is monotonic increasing?
Suppose
$$
\phi(y)=\left(2^y-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}\right)^{1/y}
$$
where $\Delta\ge 0$ is a fixed integer, $y\ge \Delta+2$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Our aim is to prove that for all non-negative integer $\Delta\ge 0$, $\phi(y)$ is increase on $[\Delta+2,+\infty)$.

There's a trial that, for $y\ge 2\Delta-2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\phi(y+1)}{\phi(y)}
    &=\frac{\left(2^{y+1}-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}\right)^{1/{y+1}}}{\left(2^y-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}\right)^{1/y}}\\
    &=\left(\frac{\left(2^{y+1}-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}\right)^{\frac{y}{y+1}}}{2^y-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}}\right)^{1/y}\\
    &=\left(\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}\right)^{\frac{y}{y+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^y}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}}\right)^{1/y}\\
    &\ge \left(\frac{1-\frac{y}{y+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}}{1-\frac{1}{2^y}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}}\right)^{1/y}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Where Bernoulli’s inequality is used. Now we can show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{y}{y+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}-\frac{1}{2^y}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}
    &=\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\left(\frac{y}{y+1}\binom{y+1}{i}-2\binom{y}{i}\right)\\
    &=\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}\left(\frac{y}{y+1}\cdot\frac{y+1}{y+1-i}-2\right)\\
    &=\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\frac{y-2(y+1-i)}{y+1-i}\binom{y}{i}\\
    &\le \frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\frac{-2\Delta+2-2+2i}{y+1-i}\binom{y}{i}\\
    &\le \frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\frac{2(i-\Delta)}{y+1-i}\binom{y}{i}\\
    &\le 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, $\frac{1-\frac{y}{y+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y+1}{i}}{1-\frac{1}{2^y}\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i}}\ge 1$, then $\frac{\phi(y+1)}{\phi(y)}\ge 1^{1/y}=1$.
But when $\Delta+2\le y\le 2\Delta-3$, I have no idea how to prove $\phi(y+1)\ge \phi(y)$. The following approximation of the summation of binomial coefficients may be helpful but I don't know how to use it:

when $k/n\le 1/2$, for all $1\le k<n$,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{8k(1-k/n)}}\cdot 2^{nH(k/n)} \le \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}\le2^{nH(k/n)} 
$$
where $H(q)=-q\log_2 q-(1-q)\log_2(1-q)=H(1-q)$. The reference of this approximation is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient.


There's a similar but more complex problem: Suppose $\varphi(y)$ is the largest real root of equation $$z^{y+1}-z^y=2^y-\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta}\binom{y}{i},$$ prove that $\varphi(y)$ is also monotonic increasing on $[\Delta+2,+\infty)$. Here $y$ and $\Delta$ are also both integers.


Let
$$
f_\Delta(y)
= 2^y-\sum_{i=0}^\Delta \binom{y}{i}
= \sum_{i=\Delta+1}^y \binom{y}{i}.
$$
First, note that $f_\Delta(y)<2^y$ since $\sum_{i=0}^y\binom{y}{i}=2^y$ and $\Delta\ge0$.
Next, using $\binom{y+1}{i}=\binom{y}{i-1}+\binom{y}{i}$, we get
$$
f_\Delta(y+1)
= f_{\Delta-1}(y)+f_\Delta(y)
= 2f_\Delta(y)+\binom{y}{\Delta}
> 2f_\Delta(y).
$$
So, we now have $f_\Delta(y)<2^y$ and $f_\Delta(y+1)>2f_\Delta(y)$ which is all we need to prove that $\phi(y)=f_\Delta(y)^{1/y}$ is increasing: eg,
since $\phi(y)<2$ for all $y$,
$$
\phi(y+1)^{y+1} = f_\Delta(y+1)
> 2f_\Delta(y) = 2\phi(y)^y > \phi(y)^{y+1}
\implies \phi(y+1)>\phi(y).
$$

Thanks! I got $f_{\Delta}(y+1)=2f_{\Delta}(y)+\binom{y}{\Delta}$ but I ignored $f_{\Delta}(y)<2^y$.
